# How can I Change datetime format with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm keeping the date in the database with this format.

```
date("o-m-d H:i:s");
```

and I need that date like this format.

```
date("dmo");
```

how can i convert it to this.

Comment: Can you post your so far tried efforts ?

Comment: $date = substr($date, 0, 11);
$year = sbustr($date, 0,4);
$month = substr($date, 5,7);
$day = substr($date, 8,11);

$editDate = $year.$month.$day;

Comment: Question is not clear, explain a bit, is that you save date as `date("o-m-d H:i:s");` in DB and while retrieving you want them as `date("dmo");` format ?

Comment: I'm keep it in DB date("o-m-d H:i:s") with this format and I'm not retrieving to date("dmo"). I need that format for another table

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not having read the [manual](http://php.net/date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use google, couple of examples:

```
result = mysql_query("SELECT `datetime` FROM `table`");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$date = date_create($row[0]);

echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
#output: 2012-03-24 17:45:12

echo date_format($date, 'd/m/Y H:i:s');
#output: 24/03/2012 17:45:12

echo date_format($date, 'd/m/y');
#output: 24/03/12

echo date_format($date, 'g:i A');
#output: 5:45 PM

echo date_format($date, 'G:ia');
#output: 05:45pm

echo date_format($date, 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y');
#output: 5:45pm on Saturday 24th March 2012
```

Answer (score 1):

Here what you can do , when you set the date as

```
date("o-m-d H:i:s");
```

It will be saved in the DB something as `2014-06-13 14:35:43`

Now while selecting the date from the DB you can use `date_format` to change the date to any desired format.

```
mysql> select date_format('2014-06-13 14:35:43','%Y%m%d') as date ;
+----------+
| date     |
+----------+
| 20140613 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So in your query change the hardcoded value with the column name something as

```
select date_format(colname,'%Y%m%d') as date from mytable;
```

Learn more about date format in mysql here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date("dmo", strtotime($mysqldate));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of your database definition, not PHP. MySQL only support date in certain formats. I don't think you can use date("dmo") in the raw database input or output. Besides, the timezone would always be confusing.

I'd recommend to store you date/time format in unix timestamp (seconds from 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) and convert to whatever you like with `date('some format', $timestamp);`.

The database field should be a `int(11) unsigned not null default 0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select unix_timestamp(datecolumn) as date from yourtable
```

In php:

```
$str = date("dmo", $row["date"]);
```

This used unix time as numbers which is quite faster than string operations to format the date in the database, then parse it in php and format it again.